# Association rules in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a User model, a Listing model and an Order model. A user can either place an order or publish a listing which others can place an order for. Thus, a User can be customer as well as supplier.

My Order model has listing_id, from_id and to_id.

My question is, how can I set up associations between these models ? I read the rails guide on associations but the example there were dealing with separate customer and supplier models.

Comment: First question, am I correct that the `from_id` and `to_id` would both point to a `User` object? Second question, can you explain more about what you're looking for; are you not sure how to describe the relationships (meaning, are you unsure whether you should use `belongs_to` or `has_many` etc), or something else?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure what relationships to use and why should I use something over another. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listings, :foreign_key => :supplier_id, :inverse_of => :supplier
  has_many :orders, :foreign_key => :customer_id, :inverse_of => :customer
end

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :supplier, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :order
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :listings
end
```

Comment: I am not very what you did here so I am going to read up more on ActiveRecord and Associations. Will accept the answer after having understood it. Many thanks.